# Find the difference between the strings in arraylist in java

Tags: java, string, list

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add("test");
        a.add("test2");
        a.add("mark3");
        a.add("testtest");
        a.add("testapple");
        a.add("test1apple");
        a.add("markapple");
        a.add("testmark");
        a.add("test2");
        a.add("mark3");
        a.add("testapple1");
```

simillarly the size of the list is 10000(it can be more than 10000). here i need to find the what are the duplicate values exists in the list (**test2,mark3**) and what are the values having  difference = 1 (**test,test2,testapple,test1apple,testapple1**)

something i need to show like below
**duplicate: test2,mark3**
**1 difference : test,test2,testapple,test1apple,testapple1**

for this im doing the traditional way of looping the list to get the result like below

```
for(i=0;i<a.size();i++){
    for(j=i+1;j<a.size();j++){
       // logic
    }
}
```

whether im doing correct or is there any other way to achieve,because if i gone with the above loop logic im facing performance issue

Comment: test and testapple will gives the diif of '5' but i want is what are the values having diff = '1'?

Comment: @GhostCat There is a "1 difference" between `test` and `test2`. There is also a 1 difference between `testapple` and `testapple1`.

Comment: What would be the difference between "test" and "text"?

Comment: difference is 1 ('x')

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Set` for better performance.

```java
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add("test");
a.add("test2");
a.add("mark3");
a.add("testtest");
a.add("testapple");
a.add("markapple");
a.add("testmark");
a.add("test2"); // dup
a.add("mark3"); // dup
a.add("testapple1");
a.add("test2"); // triple

Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
Set<String> dup = new HashSet<>();
for (String s : a)
    if (! set.add(s)) // add returns false if value already seen
        dup.add(s);
System.out.println("duplicates: " + dup);

for (String s : set) {
    if (s.length() > 1) {
        String base = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
        if (set.contains(base)) {
            System.out.println("1 difference: " + base + ", " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
duplicates: [test2, mark3]
1 difference: test, test2
1 difference: testapple, testapple1
```

Comment: what if the values having test1apple?here the values can be any type of string.

Comment: @SundarG Since "difference = 1" is currently defined in the question as being the same string except one of them has 1 extra character at the end, that is a problem I don't need to solve. This answer perfectly answers the question, with a high performance result.

Comment: but the above logic wont give the desired result.

Comment: @SundarG It gave the desired result for the question, as the question was specified.